# How to score the orthogonality between two matrix?

Tags: orthogonality, scoring-algorithm

I have two matrices that I would like to know how much orthogonal they are with respect to one another. I was wondering if anyone knows a good scoring metric to score the amount of orthogonality between the two matrices?

To explain this more:

I am training a neural net, and I would like to test whether the two layers in the neural net are disentangled. Based on what I read, one way is to measure whether the two layers are learning orthogonal features. And I am looking for a mathematical way of measuring this.

Comment: First you will have to explain what you **mean** by the "orthogonality" of two matrices.

Comment: $\langle A,B\rangle = \operatorname{Tr}(AB^T)$ is the usual (Hilbert-Schmidt) inner product between matrices. The corresponding norm is the Frobenius norm.

Comment: I edited the problem I hope that is more clear now @user247327